# Generating DRDL file for MongoDb Atlas for use with MongoDb Bi Connector

Tags: mongodb, analytics, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to set up Mongo Db Bi Connector in order to carry out some analytics on my MongoDb Atlas Cluster. I am following the instructions here: https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/tutorial/connecting-to-atlas/

However, when trying to generate the DRDL file as specified running the following (with my information):

```
mongodrdl --host <domain0>.mongodb.net:27017,<domain1>.mongodb.net:27017,... -u <username> -p <password> --ssl --authenticationDatabase=admin -d <database>
```

I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mongodrdl

  Reason: image not found

Abort trap: 6
```

I am not sure what is the cause of this or what it means.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud) uses TLS/SSL to encrypt connections and enforces authentication *by default.*

[MongoDB Connector for BI](https://www.mongodb.com/products/bi-connector) supports TLS/SSL and requires SSL library to be installed. See also the [Installation step for installing OpenSSL on the manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/installation/#install-openssl)

Assuming you're using OSX, then you can run the following:

```
sudo brew update && sudo brew install openssl
```